# RDLC Report showing data on other page if data is more

Tags: reportviewer, rdlc

I have a bill application in winforms using reportviewer and showing rdlc report in it, I have a main report and a subreport in it
now the problem is that when i have less than 40 items it shows the report fine, but if its more than that the data comes from next page, please see the reports and ourput

Main Report
[image: Main RDLC Report]

SubReport
[image]

Normal display when 25 records
[image: Normal display when 25 records]

When it is 40 records pg1
[image: When it is 40 records]

Second page
[image: Second page]

any help will be appriciated

Answer (score 2):

try Unchecking `Keep together on one page if possible` option in `Page break options.`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using vs2010, and it looks like you're in 08? so it might be a little different but I'll give it a try (mostly because I am looking for some help as well and I know how frustrating it is using this when there's not a lot of "quality" answers out there for specific problems).

In the subreport rdlc file, make sure that the "PageBreak" property (on the table containing your columns) isn't set to "start."  I would just set it to "none."

What I believe that is happening is that it's moving it to the next page because it won't fit on the first page.  what you can do to try to get around that is include everything on the main report in a rectangle (in the rectangle, set pagebreak = none, and keeptogether=true [I'm not sure if you actually want keeptogether=true... if it squeezes everything onto one page by resizing it set it to false]).

Hope I helped